# Not able to decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have the following function to encrypt and decrypt id. But `$id=298` gives `�����bt` after decryption.

Error message is:

> Invalid utf8 character string: '\x8A\xBC\x86\xFD'

I'm not able change key since I have more than 300 uses using this $key for login.

```
function mencrypt($input,$key)
{
    $key = substr(md5($key),0,24);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open ('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $key, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic ($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit ($td);
    mcrypt_module_close ($td);
    return trim(chop(url_base64_encode($encrypted_data)));
}
 
function mdecrypt($input,$key)
{
    $input = trim(chop(url_base64_decode($input)));
    $td = mcrypt_module_open ('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
    $key = substr(md5($key),0,24);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted_data = mdecrypt_generic ($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit ($td);
    mcrypt_module_close ($td);
    return trim(chop($decrypted_data));
} 

   $id = 298;
   $key ="21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3";
   echo $encrypted_id = mencrypt($id,$key);
   echo "<br>";
   echo mdecrypt($encrypted_id,$key);
```

Comment: the `$iv` should be that same for encrypt and decrypt, but yours is random

Comment: I set $iv=12345678 for both functions, but it still gives an error. Invalid utf8 character string: '\x8A\xBC\x86\xFD'